# Output of layer in CNN with equal dim of feature

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network, autoencoder, feature-engineering

I read a bit about autoencoders and read that encoder transform data from $\mathbb{R}^{N \times D} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{N\times d}$$ space.
I wrote CNN autoencoder with for example one layer like this:

```
  self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(1, 1, 5)
```

but when I apply `x = F.relu(self.conv1(x))` of course I get an image with smaller dimensions (if I had the dimension `torch.Size([1, 400, 1024])` at the beginning)
after the operation I have `torch.Size([1, 396, 1020])`.

It is clear that convolution reduces the dimension of the image (that's all clear :) ), but I'm interested in whether there is a way to keep the number of features and then fill the others with zeros, and if that would be a step in the right direction, the question arises as to which features to fill with zeros .
P.S. I use only one channel because I want the final result to be in a 2d matrix, and my images are gray scale anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to add a *padding='same'* option

```py
self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(1, 1, 5, padding='same')
```

This is the usual way of ensuring output dimensions don't get shrunk
when applying convolutional layers. It pads the original image before
applying the convolution, by default with zeros, rather than padding the result.

(If this were Tensorflow I would be certain, but it looks like torch works
the same way. https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Conv2d.html)

Comment: When I put in encoder this  
self.t_conv1 = nn.ConvTranspose2d(1, 1, 3, padding="same")
self.t_conv2 = nn.ConvTranspose2d(1, 1, 5, padding="same")
 I got dimenson after first and second layer (400, 1024). But I want that for example after first layer get for example (400, 512) and after second for example (400, 256)...

Comment: The usual way of dropping an image dimension by a factor of 2 is by using a MaxPool2d layer (with kernel_size=2) after one or more convolutional layers. This will drop both the x and y dimensions of each image by a factor of 2. Usually (if processing images) this would go hand-in-hand with an increasing number of channels so that the convolutional layers can identify multiple features in the images. I'm not sure why you need to drop only one dimension by a factor of 2?

Comment: It is not necessarily important that they double down, it is just an example. But how to achieve that my x value is always preserved (as written above in the encoder definition) - so that it is reduced from (400, 1024) to (400, 1022) for example?

Comment: OK, I see what you're trying to do. You should be able to apply different padding to x and y. So to go from (400,1024) to (400,1022) I think you need kernel_size=3, padding=(1,0). The final dimension size (for either x or y) is n_out = floor((n_in + 2*padding - kernel_size)/stride + 1)

Comment: However... I'm just wondering if that first dimension (the 400 above) is the batch dimension? It would seem a bit strange to convolve over it if it is, so I'm wondering if you might be better using 1D convolutions here

Comment: This is the original size (1, 400, 1024), but already after applying the convolution I get this (1, 398, 1020), whereas after another convolution I get ([1, 398, 1018]). So why only the first time when I apply convolution the first dimension decreases?
The code is self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(1, 1, 5, padding=(1,0))
            self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(1, 1, 3, padding=(1,0))

Comment: If kernel size is 5, you need padding=(2,0) to keep the first dimension the same size.

Comment: Is there maybe some way to insert the maxpool so that I leave the first dimension of the image intact?

Comment: Yes, in maxpool2d you can, for example, set kernel_size=(1,2), stride=(1,2) or kernel_size=(2,2), stride=(1,2), padding=(1,0). The key to understanding how this works in general is the formula I posted above, which works for both convolutions and pooling. n_out = floor((n_in + 2*padding - kernel_size)/stride + 1). May be worth doing a small spreadsheet exercise on this to get the hang of how it works?

Comment: Sorry, I think I got the numbers wrong in the second example in that last comment. But the first one makes more sense anyway,on reflection

Comment: I did the convolution Conv2d(1, 1, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 0))
and after that maxpool MaxPool2d(kernel_size=(1, 2), stride=(1, 2), padding=0)
Which meant that from the initial dimension which was (400, 1024) after convolution I got to (400, 1022), and after maxpool (400,509). (I don't write 1 as the first dimension because torch.size is actually (1,400,1024).
I tried setting various parameters for convtranspose, but I never found suitable parameters that would return the dimension (400,509) back to (400,1022) in the encoder part. So if you can help a little with that?